# Проблема адаптера беспроводных сетей Qualcomm Atheros

Tags: драйвер, router, wireless

Всем привет!
Пару дней назад возникла проблема с беспроводным соединением. До этого все работало прекрасно и причина неожиданной ошибки мне неясна. В общем перестал работать wi-fi, сперва я подумала на роутер, перезагрузила его несколько раз- но это не помогло. Потом прочитала, что проблема может быть в драйверах на ноуте. Зашла через диспетчер устройств и действительно, увидела, что беспроводной адаптер обозназен желтым треугольничком. Я вообще убрала роутер и подключила интернет напрямую через кабель, т.е. кабель вставила в ноут. Вот скриншот, на котором видно, что при ноуте подключенном к инету через кабель адаптер вайфая все равно остался с желтым треугольником, поэтому я сделала вывод, что проблема в драйвере, а не в роутере. Но устранить эту проблему никак не могу. Обновить система его не дает, как и удалить и заново инсталировать тоже. Мой ноутбук Toshiba Satellite L750, а драйвер который нужен Qualcomm Atheros AR9002WB-1NG Wireless Network Adapter, но что-то нигде его не смогла найти в формате .exe. Ниже прилагаю парочку скринов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]